# Exporting high-precision Complex number into a text file without apostrophe

Tags: export, data, precision-and-accuracy

I have a following problem. My code is for simplicity:

```
h = Table[{SetPrecision[i, 3], SetPrecision[(1+I)/(1 + i^2), 50]}, {i, 0, 
    10, 1/100}];
Export["test.txt", h, "Table"]
```

I want those number to have really 50 decimal places. But the output test.txt reads:

```
0   1.`50.+1.`50.*I
0.01    0.9999000099990000999900009999000099990000999900009999000099990000999900009999`50.+0.9999000099990000999900009999000099990000999900009999000099990000999900009999`50.*I
...
```

Why are there those '50? It really annoys me and I can't get rid of this. This problem occurs when complex numbers are involved (that 1+I part), but the output is correct when only reals are exported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
h = Table[{SetPrecision[i, 3], SetPrecision[(1+I)/(1 + i^2), 50]}, {i, 0, 10, 1/100}];
Block[{$NumberMarks = False},
    Export["test.txt", h, "Table"]
];
```

Comment: Well, that takes care of that! Thank you.